# Dropdown with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm working on my site by editing a template but there is a drop down menu that does not work.
The drop-down menu CSS is missing.
How can I fix it with CSS and/or with JS?
Below is the HTML code:

```
<a href="#" id="ddnmenu">Bentornato {$mybb->user['username']}! <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
<div id="ddnmenu_popup" class="popup_menu" style="display: none;">
  <div class="popup_item_container">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/usercp.php" class="popup_item">User Panel<i class="fa fa-user menuadj"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_item_container">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/usercp.php?action=profile" class="popup_item">Edit Profile<i class="fa fa-pencil menuadj"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_item_container">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/usercp.php?action=options" class="popup_item">Edit Options<i class="fa fa-cogs menuadj"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_item_container">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/usercp.php?action=avatar" class="popup_item">Edit Avatar<i class="fa fa-picture-o menuadj"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_item_container">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/usercp.php?action=editsig" class="popup_item" style="padding-bottom: 4px;">Edit Signature<i class="fa fa-paint-brush menuadj"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_item_container">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/member.php?action=logout&amp;logoutkey={$mybb->user['logoutkey']}" class="popup_item">{$lang->welcome_logout}!<i class="fa fa-power-off menuadj"></i>
                        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit:
I used the solution you suggested to me with jquery, but now there is another problem...

When the menu opens the side button moves beneath it, thus ruining the entire menu..

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: set the ```style="display:block"``` first

Comment: @syarul Ok, but now it's always visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code with jquery :

Add jquery library - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Then put this code in script section :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ddnmenu').click(function(){
    $('#ddnmenu_popup').slideToggle();
  })
})
```

Add this css:

```
#ddnmenu_popup{
   position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: There are no differences, do you want me to place the whole code?

Comment: Just add this in your css - #ddnmenu_popup{
   position: absolute;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$( ".popup_menu" ).toggle();` on clicking on the link `#ddnmenu`. But first you should remove `style="display: none;"`

```
$( "#ddnmenu" ).click(function() {
   $( ".popup_menu" ).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style property via JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<a onclick="openDropdown()" href="#" id="ddnmenu">Bentornato {$mybb->user['username']}! <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
<div id="ddnmenu_popup" class="popup_menu" style="display: none;">
   ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
function openDropdown() {
    document.getElementById('ddnmenu_popup').style.display = 'block';
}
```